# Dynamic voice prompts in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I'm the president, chief bottle washer and IT guy at a small non-profit. We've been using OpenVBX for years for our IVR, but due to Twilio's lack of support for OpenVBX, and the need to keep PHP current, I decided to recreate our IVR using Twilio Studio.  I got that done yesterday, but it utilizes computerized voices for all of the prompts.

Using OpenVBX, you could have the system dial a phone and have someone record the message for each prompt, but there's no such capability (that I know of) with Studio.  How do I replicate that functionality or how do others' build a system where you can easily update the voice prompts without having to edit the Studio script?

Thanks, Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There isn't an API for updating Studio Flows, so you couldn't completely automate this process to replace the voice prompts.

One idea I had was that if you get the recording you could store it in [Twilio Assets](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/assets) and then add the URL to the Say/Play widget. Then, when you update the recording, upload it again with the same URL. I'm unsure how long Studio will cache audio files of recordings, but it might make it possible to update the recordings without altering the Flow itself.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.  It appears that this is along the lines of what I was looking for.  However, the documentation on how to implement it is a bit thin, so I think that I'll implement a different solution while I work towards one based on Assets.